# Adding CSS files in magento

Tags: magento

I want to add some CSS files to a product detail page in magento so where can I add that, I  saw catalog.xml, where js files were added but didn't find a place where I can add CSS files. So can anyone please tell that where will I add those? I want to add actually thickbox.css

thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that same place where you add Javascript there's another function called addCss

```
<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>directory/file.css</stylesheet></action>
```